# Undefined variable array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I get an error on line 15 that says "Undefined variable: row2". How can I resolve this?

```
$limit = 20;

$res1 = mysql_query('SELECT *
                        FROM contact
                        WHERE name = "Greg"');
$res2 = mysql_query('SELECT name
                        FROM contact c, passport p
                        ON c.idNum = p.iNum
                        WHERE date >= "2015-03-03" AND t< "2015-03-21');

if(!$res1 && !$res2) {
    die('Query no valid: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    while(($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1)) || ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2))) {
        $sub = $row1['num'] - $row2['num'];
        if($sub <= $limit) {
            echo '<br>row name is: ', $row2['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get a number from the first table (it only results to just Greg's row). Then subtract it with the numbers from the results of the second table. The result of this is placed into the sub variable and it's check to see if it's <= 20. If yes, it prints out the row. If not, it goes back to while loop to check another row. Am I going about the right way so far?

Comment: You're subtracting `$row2['num']`, but only selecting `name` in your second query

Comment: So there is no `$row2['num']` as you did not select that column

Comment: Well..You haven't selected the `num` column in your second query so that's why it shows as undefined.!

Comment: Lazy evaluation means that $row2 willl not exist until all $res1 results have  been fetched

Comment: This could be done using a `JOIN` statement in MySQL, using the `c.idNum`

Comment: Okay, I see. Terrible mistake by me! Thanks for pointing that out to me

Comment: @Sean Okay, thanks for advising. What's wrong with ON statement, by the way?

Comment: @mrteeth the `ON` is fine. I realized that I misread your code. I was thinking you could do a `JOIN` with `$res1` & `$res2`. But now that I reread your code, it looks like you are comparing 1 row from `contact` against all rows from `contact c, passport p` in the date range. So nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : Select all columns in your 2nd Query if `num` is already available in your columns so your problem will be solved then.!

**Note : Try to replace `||` with `&&` and you will be good to go.**

By using `||` or `OR` as in conceptional language as I would say it.You are making the code like in a way that either and only one will pass but if you are passing both ones so then you should replace `||` with `&&` so that's why your `$row2` will be already created then so it will be available for more operation.!

```
$limit = 20;

$res1 = mysql_query('SELECT *
                        FROM contact
                        WHERE name = "Greg"');
$res2 = mysql_query('SELECT *
                        FROM contact c, passport p
                        ON c.idNum = p.iNum
                        WHERE date >= "2015-03-03" AND t< "2015-03-21');

if(!$res1 && !$res2) {
    die('Query no valid: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    while(($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2))) {
        $sub = $row1['num'] - $row2['num'];
        if($sub <= $limit) {
            echo '<br>row name is: ', $row2['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you fixed the query but `$row2` will be undefined variable still.

Comment: @Umair Shah Yousafzai, I tried it and it still gives me the same error message.

Comment: @mrteeth : Try `var_dump` OR  `print_r` to confirm if you are getting any data from both executed queries.!

Comment: @Umair Shah Yousafzai, the error has been resolved. Thanks a lot! However, I'm not getting any results back. There's 200 records in my database and I hoping to get back 50 (I manually checked the ones that fit my criteria). I'll try and fix this.

Comment: @mrteeth : Sure!!! No Problem.Try to make it your habit to first check the executed data from your database by using `var_dump` OR `print_r` and then move forward with your code.Also mark your answer if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Also when using print_r, should I use it like this: "print_r($row2);"?

Comment: The same with var_dump, should I use it like this "var_dump($row2);"? Also what line should I place it?

Comment: @mrteeth : Yes..You are using it the right way & Don't hesitate to ask for help anwhere you need.

Comment: @Umair Shah Yousafzai, what like of my code should I be using `var_dump` and `print_r`? I placed it after the echo statement and it didn't display any data.

Comment: @mrteeth : Use `var_dump` OR `print_r` after fetching data from database through passing the array variable which contains the fetched data which in your case is `$row1` and `$row2` also make your habit to use `while` loop less than other loops as foreach or for loop.foreach and forloops are better to use instead of while.

Comment: @Umair Shah Yousafzai: Interesting, regarding for/eachloop. I tried to do this and it didn't work. Is it okay if you can give me an example code?

Comment: @mrteeth :Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326346/how-to-use-multiple-arrays-in-single-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `while()` loop's condition. Consider this example:

```
$a = 1;

if ($a == 1 || $b = 2) {
  var_dump(isset($b));
}
```

Output of `var_dump()` will be `boolean false` because `$b` does not exist, which is the same case why your `$row2` is undefined.

The thing is, while evaluation conditions with `||`, PHP will stop evaluating other conditions once the match is found, so other comparisons or assignments on the right side will not be performed.

Change your `while` to be like this, you need both `$row1` and `$row2` anyway:

```
while(($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2))) {
```

(note the `&&` instead of `||`)

Also, looks like you may want to use `SELECT c.*` in your second query, too, because you're only selecting the `name` column, and trying to use `num` too.

Comment: thanks for the advise, regarding &&, no error messages anymore. Unfortunately, I'm not retrieving any data. :( So I have to keep working on it.