# How to print two array in one foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, laravel-blade

I'm print this two array in this forech loop. if i select last checkbox item after submit it will check first item didn't checked last item. that is my problem.

**Here is my code example image**
[image: Here is my code example image]

**Problem**
[image: problem]

I'm also try other question answer but didn't work for me.

1. [How to use multiple arrays in " single " foreach() loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326346)
2. [Two arrays in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803)
3. [How to display two arrays in one foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345432)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code. Not a image

Comment: Ok @Andreas. I will  add.

Comment: try to use diffrent id and classes for your checkbox input

Comment: debug it by echoing your $qids[$key]->group_id in the html.
you are checking only using isset. do you also want to check based on $data->group_id == $qids[$key]->group_id?.

I can't tell precisly unless you post your code also

Comment: Hi @RAUSHANKUMAR try with different id and class. but nothing changed.

Comment: Hello @r4ccoon I can't edit my stackoverflow question. I'm added ans with my blade code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm solved my problem using two php array function.**

1. [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
2. [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

**Here is my solved code:**

```
    @elseif(isset($groupsData) && !$groupsData->isEmpty() or isset($qids) && !$qids->isEmpty())
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        $gids = array_column($qids->toArray(),'group_id');
    ?>
    @foreach($groupsData as $key => $data)
        <?php $i++;  ?>
        <tr>
            <td><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="groups_id[]" value="{{ $data->id }}" class="check_checkbox" @if(in_array($data->id,$gids)) {{ 'checked' }} @endif >
            </label></td>
            <td>{{ $i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->group_name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My blade code:

```
@elseif(isset($groupsData) && !$groupsData->isEmpty() or isset($qids) && !$qids->isEmpty())
<?php $i = 0; ?>
@foreach($groupsData as $key => $data)
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="groups_id[]" value="{{ $data->id }}" class="check_checkbox" @if(isset($qids[$key]->group_id)) {{ 'checked' }} @endif ></label></td>
        <td>{{ $i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->group_name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach @else
```

This is print_r code:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
```

(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\QuizGroupQuestionId Object
                (
                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => quiz_id
                            [1] => group_id
                            [2] => question_id
                        )

```
                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => deleted_at
                    )

                [connection:protected] => mysql
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [incrementing] => 1
                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [withCount:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 12
                        [quiz_id] => 1
                        [group_id] => 8
                        [question_id] => 
                        [created_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [updated_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [deleted_at] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 12
                        [quiz_id] => 1
                        [group_id] => 8
                        [question_id] => 
                        [created_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [updated_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [deleted_at] => 
                    )

                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [events:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [timestamps] => 1
                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [forceDeleting:protected] => 
            )

        [1] => App\QuizGroupQuestionId Object
            (
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => quiz_id
                        [1] => group_id
                        [2] => question_id
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => deleted_at
                    )

                [connection:protected] => mysql
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [incrementing] => 1
                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [withCount:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 13
                        [quiz_id] => 1
                        [group_id] => 9
                        [question_id] => 
                        [created_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [updated_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [deleted_at] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 13
                        [quiz_id] => 1
                        [group_id] => 9
                        [question_id] => 
                        [created_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [updated_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [deleted_at] => 
                    )

                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [events:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [timestamps] => 1
                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [forceDeleting:protected] => 
            )

        [2] => App\QuizGroupQuestionId Object
            (
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => quiz_id
                        [1] => group_id
                        [2] => question_id
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => deleted_at
                    )

                [connection:protected] => mysql
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [incrementing] => 1
                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [withCount:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14
                        [quiz_id] => 1
                        [group_id] => 10
                        [question_id] => 
                        [created_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [updated_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [deleted_at] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14
                        [quiz_id] => 1
                        [group_id] => 10
                        [question_id] => 
                        [created_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [updated_at] => 2017-07-22 18:56:54
                        [deleted_at] => 
                    )

                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [events:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [timestamps] => 1
                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [forceDeleting:protected] => 
            )

    )
```

)

rendered html code:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><label><input name="group_all" class="checked_all" type="checkbox"> Select All</label></th>
<th>#</th>
<th>Group Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="groups_id[]" value="4" class="check_checkbox"  checked  ></label></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>jkl</td>
    </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="groups_id[]" value="5" class="check_checkbox"  checked  ></label></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>mno</td>
    </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="groups_id[]" value="7" class="check_checkbox"  checked  ></label></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>rthytr4y</td>
    </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="groups_id[]" value="8" class="check_checkbox"  ></label></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>erter</td>
    </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="groups_id[]" value="9" class="check_checkbox"  ></label></td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>wetret</td>
    </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="groups_id[]" value="10" class="check_checkbox"  ></label></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>yhjjyukji</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with blade/laravel, but i can tell you how to debug. you could do print_r($qids). before these code block, and see what's inside $qids.

you can see the resulting html, which radiobutton has the "checked" printed.

Comment: there is array of qids. showing array list. Do you tell me how i will checked checkbox value in this way above my code.

Comment: give us your rendered html

Comment: Hello @r4ccoon I'm update my question ans with print_r code and rendered html code and i'm using html checkbox not radio buttons. that's why checked multiple input.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you can see that all radio buttons are checked. you need to have better check. use this check, please fix the syntax according to the blade syntax. but basically you are comparing group_id in $qids with id in $data.

```
@if(isset($qids[$key]->group_id) && $qids[$key]->group_id == $data->$id ) {{ 'checked' }} @endif
```

Comment: Same problem, it's checked first checkbox after checking last checkbox.

Comment: you need to track your last checked id/ submitted it. easiest i can think of is to put it in the url parameter. 

the idea is, once submitted, redirect to e.g.:
page.php?last_checked_id=3

than you compare it in your radiobutton line.

if($data->id == $_GET['last_checked_id') 

if it worked, you need to make your code pretty by using laravel way to get GET parameter. and then think a bit about the security issues (if any) caused by this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable ans.

Comment: Hi @r4ccoon I'm solved my this problem and added those code.
Thanks again for your help :)